# Compare two JSON file and output unmatched values from a file using Jq in Shell script

Tags: json, shell, unix, jq, diff

How can I output the objects from a JSON file which doesn't match in another JSON file. For Example,

file1:

```
[
{ 
  "name": "ABC",
  "age": "23",
  "address": "xyz"
},
{
  "name": "DEF",
  "age": "24",
  "address": "pqr"
}
]
```

file2:

```
[
{ 
  "name": "ABC",
  "age": "23",
  "address": "xyz"
},
{
  "name": "GHI",
  "age": "24",
  "address": "pqr"
}
]
```

I want the output from file2 which doesn't match in file1. Example:

output file:

```
[
{
  "name": "GHI",
  "age": "24",
  "address": "pqr"
}
]
```

I am looking to do it in shell script using Jq.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what exactly means match" or non-match. All keys and values the same? Additional keys? Same "name" value? Is the order of the structures the same in both files or do you want to match structures by e.g. the "name" value? What about additional or missing structures? If you already tried something, show your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jq minus operator does exactly what you need. Just use `--slurpfile` to get both files into variables:

```
jq -n --slurpfile file1 file1.json --slurpfile file2 file2.json '$file2[0] - $file1[0]'
```